# How to set component output binding from ui bootstrap's uibModal.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Given a component with an output binding, like this:

```
angular.module('app').component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'myComponent.html',

    bindings: {
        onSelect: '&'
    },

    controller: class {

        selectedItems = [];

        // called when the user clicks a button, outputs an array of selected items
        selectItems() {
            this.onSelect({items: this.selectedItems});
        }

    }
});
```

If used as a tag, I can get the selected items with this code:

```
<my-component on-select='$ctrl.select(items)' />
```

How do I achieve the same thing with ui.bootstrap's `uibModal.open`?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
$uibModal.open({
    component: 'myComponent',
    resolve: {
        onSelect: () => (items) => { console.log('parent event handler', items); }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(i know it's probably too late, but for future reference...)

Actually you were quite close to the solution. You need to pass the function you wish to be called outside of the component as you did, but inside the component you need to get the reference via the "resolve" binding.

```
angular.module('app').component('myComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'modal.html',

  bindings: {
    resolve: '<'
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  controller: function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.ok = function() {
      vm.resolve.onSelect({
        item: 'from modal'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

In the $uibModal.open function  you need to resolve the desired object within a function. In this case, you want the onSelect to be a function, so you need to return it. This is the function that is called when you send an output event from within the component (vm.resolve.onSelect( { ... })).

```
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $uibModal.open({
      component: 'myComponent',
      resolve: {
        onSelect: function() {
          return function(params) {
             alert('hooray: ' + params.item);
          };
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/uf5zWX6ltSA0R1qJpDRL